# Convert KML overlay to PNG overlay for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, geoxml3

I have a large KML file with a lot of polygons and if I try to load it into my google maps application, with the JS library geoXML3, the javascript stops with timeouts. With small KMLs it's not a problem.

Now, my idea is to convert the KML file to a PNG image and give this image as an OverlayLayer to the google maps api. Possibly the converter should support the google maps zoomlevel to create adaptet images.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to realize this conversion. Are there any existing solutions like php scripts or anything else?

Kind Regards

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)?  Or import your KML into a FusionTable and use a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. The KML is not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I have converted a KML file into a PNG layer using the following method:

1. Convert the KML file to an Illustrator file using the method on this page http://dodona.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/how-do-i-open-my-google-maps-route-in-adobe-illustrator/
2. Convert the Illustrator file to a PNG using Photoshop
3. Create a PNG layer from the PNG file using MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.org/)

I now have a PNG map tile layer I can use in Google Maps or Bing Maps.